# I am trying to sum inputs from a userform

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to sum inputs from a userform into one cell, the inputs are numbers so i would think it would be easy, but instead of summing the inputs, the code I'm using (Below) is concatenating them like strings instead

```
Sub Days()

A = input1.Value + input2.Value + input3.Value + input4.Value
B = input5.Value + input6.Value = input7.Value + input8.Value


If Box1.Value = True Then
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value + A
    Range("A2").Value = Range("A2").Value + B
End If

If Box2.Value = True Then
    Range("B1").Value = Range("B1").Value + A
    Range("B2").Value = Range("B2").Value + B
End If

If Box2.Value = True Then
    Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + A
    Range("C2").Value = Range("C2").Value + B
End If

End Sub
```

I have already tried Dim both A & B as integer first, not using the variables at all and just having the addition of all inputs in each if statement, all with a data type error after the first and the same concatenation issue with the second

Currently, If the inputs were 4,3,7,2,8,10,5,9 instead of adding 16 & 22 to the appropriate range, it spits out 4372 & 81059

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
A = CInt(input1.Value) + CInt(input2.Value) + CInt(input3.Value) + CInt(input4.Value)
```

...assuming all your values are integers - use CLng/CDbl etc if you have other types of number.